# dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04 problem error no such device

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

[gparted photo]

I had windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 14.04 on the same hard drive.

When I switch on and the list of options to boot appears I can boot into Ubuntu ok and access all windows files, but can not boot into windows 10.

When I choose windows 10 to boot I get the message:

```
error: no such device: 27795F9B69145D5C.
press any key to continue...
```

Then the screen goes blank

I am new to Ubuntu.

```
vuletic@vuletic-Aspire-5735:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for vuletic: 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="PQSERVICE" UUID="EAEE-EB49" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="a03c32da-1e8d-4c37-8aa7-b8e8e501f63b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="C:/" UUID="27795F9B69145D5C" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="323C3EB83C3E7747" TYPE="ntfs" 
vuletic@vuletic-Aspire-5735:~$
```

```
vuletic@vuletic-Aspire-5735:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=a03c32da-1e8d-4c37-8aa7-b8e8e501f63b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
vuletic@vuletic-Aspire-5735:~$
```

```
vuletic@vuletic-Aspire-5735:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc637a1a9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    20482047    10240000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2        20482048    79077375    29297664   83  Linux
/dev/sda3   *    79079424   975055575   447988076    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       975056896   976054271      498688   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
vuletic@vuletic-Aspire-5735:~$
```

```
vuletic@vuletic-Aspire-5735:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
[sudo] password for vuletic: 
 Simple tool to repair frequent boot problems.

Website: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmphj6oekac/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmphj6oekac/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 60D8DA0B from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmphj6oekac/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 60D8DA0B: public key "Launchpad PPA for YannUbuntu" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
vuletic@vuletic-Aspire-5735:~$ 
14.04
```

```
vuletic@vuletic-Aspire-5735:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-106-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-106-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-49-generic
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda3
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-106-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-106-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-49-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda3
done
vuletic@vuletic-Aspire-5735:~$
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the output, from the `terminal` app, of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: i hope this is info you asked

Comment: The line **/dev/sda3: LABEL="C:/" UUID="27795F9B69145D5C" TYPE="ntfs"** tells me that indeed that the device IS there. What I don't see is any swap file or swap partition. Post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and a current-window-only screenshot of `gparted`. Do you have a Windows 10 install/repair disc?

Comment: i dont have windows 10 install/repair disc as i installed it from internet

Comment: Did this **ever** boot into Windows 10 after Ubuntu was installed? Are you still working on a gparted screenshot?

Comment: yes it worked with windows 8, and then with windows 10 for years, sorry dont know how to get gparted screenshot

Comment: Start `gparted` and make sure it's looking at /dev/sda. Start `screenshot` and select current-window-only and hit Take Screenshot button. Save image. Edit answer and click the little graphic icon in the toolbar to include the image. Different question... did you do a `sudo update-grub`? Can you boot Windows now?

Comment: done sudo update-grub, will try windoes now

Comment: I think that you need a `Windows install/repair disc` to fix this problem. Later, you also need to add a `swap file` or `swap partition`.

Comment: stil not working, dont know how to get windows 10 install/repair disk, on boot menu there is recovery option on sd1, while windows 10 is on sd3, then when try to run it get message; fail to get disk 2 drive letter

Comment: You can download it from Microsoft. Google it for the location.

Comment: You also need a Ubuntu Live DVD (not USB).

Comment: The Windows 10 disc image is at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: i got windows 10 disk now and ubuntu 14.04, dont know what to do now. when try to boot from windows disk and get to install windows 10, get to point where says you started booting from disk, eject disk out, boot into windows and try disk again. dont know how to run windows disk from ubuntu. any more help please?

Comment: It looks like you installed `Boot Repair`, but did you ever run it? Go to the Unity dash and type `boot` and run it. To boot the Windows disc, you enter your BIOS boot menu... F12 or something similar... and select the DVD to boot. Then when the Windows install/repair menu comes up... follow repair.

Comment: tried repair, it did not work, stil same

Answer (score 1):

it seems the OS is looking for a UUID that doesn't exist. Use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair?action=fullsearch&value=linkto%3A%22Boot-Repair%22&context=180) tool to repair the issue,install it via terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then if the simple click won't fix things,then you will post the Booting Summary for further help.

Comment: thank you sentinel, i tried your instructions and its still same

Comment: can you post the booting summary from the same tools so as i could see the errors

Comment: you should try `sudo update-grub` fit,it won't work,then you are going to have to modify `boot/grub/grub.cfg` manual,excuse that command first,if it won't work then we shall proceed with the next setup

Comment: @ArduinoSentinel you don't modify grub.cfg by hand.

Comment: no,will have to change the UUIDs correspondly on `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @ArduinoSentinel as you can see from my earlier exchange, I've got the UUID info... and it's fine... and fstab has nothing to do with grub. The only thing that's missing from the fstab is swap.

Comment: oh!yes you are right,i didn't look at it well

Comment: sorry guys, what shall i do/try next?

Comment: did you try grub update?

Comment: tried, ill enter details

Comment: after `sudo update-grub` then reboot the system and see if error persist

Comment: tried reboot and still nothing, same message error: no such device

Comment: @VULETICA did you ever find a solution for this? Currently I have to choose my OS by booting the respectove HDD via the BIOS boot menu.